# max value of a field as variable

Tags: arcpy, z-value

With the following script I was able to determine the maximum values of a column [POINT_Z] for certain groups from [ID_1].

```
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inLAS[:-4] + '_POLE_POINTS.SHP', "POLES")
    reset_layers("POLES")

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inLAS[:-4] + '_POLE_POINTS.SHP','ID_1') as max_cursor:
        for row in max_cursor:
            mast_value = sorted({row[0] for row in max_cursor})

    #iterate through the list to find highest value in field [pointz], but only in features which have the value of the element of the list "mast_value"
    field = "ID_1"
    for mast in mast_value:
        expression = field + " = " + str(mast)
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inLAS[:-4] + '_POLE_POINTS.SHP',('POINT_Z', 'FID'), where_clause=expression) as mast_cursor:
            for row1 in mast_cursor:
                print('ID ' + str(mast) + u': max altitude ' + str(max(mast_cursor)))
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("POLES", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"FID\" = " + str(max(mast_cursor)[1]))
```

With the output I can display the results. A manual check showed that the result is correct.

```
ID 1: max altitude (477.56, 5997) ID 7: max altitude (523.27, 3401) ID 16: max altitude (495.69, 3203) ID 38: max altitude (495.69, 5574) ID 39: max altitude (470.16, 5986) ID 44: max altitude (503.93, 4713) ID 63: max altitude (503.97, 4185) ID 73: max altitude (463.67, 4205) ID 75: max altitude (518.59, 2880) ID 77: max altitude (463.63, 5877) ID 79: max altitude (485.91, 5594) ID 87: max altitude (482.06, 853) ID 88: max altitude (475.2, 1836) ID 91: max altitude (492.0, 1074) ID 97: max altitude (468.77, 1323) ID 98: max altitude (462.52, 1546) ID 99: max altitude (463.81, 1294)
```

To continue working (selection), I need the corrosponding value [FID] (second value in the brackets) of the maximum value of [POINT_Z] as a variable. My attempt to write the result into a variable

```
myMastList = str(max(mast_cursor))
```

fails with an error message.

```
File "E:\Documents\LAS\Las_Wire.py", line 264, in masten
    myMastList = str(max(mast_cursor))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

How can I write the value of [FID] from the highest value of [POINT_Z] (or both [FID] and [POINT_Z]) into a variable?

Comment: thanks for your advise. I checked the expression and the expression is correct. If I remove the command arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("POLES", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"FID\" = " + str(max(mast_cursor)[1])) 

and I use instead the print command 

print(str(max(mast_cursor)[1])) I got a list like this:

5997
3401
3203
5574
5986
4713

which are the correct FID values

Comment: You want to select max `POINT_Z` point per `ID_1` Group? Do you have ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: The goal is to select the feature [FID] with the highest value in [POINT_Z] grouped with [ID_1]. [ID_1] was created after a union command and represents points within the same area. My goal now is to find the highest point within this area [ID_1], select it and copy it into a separate Shapefile for further calculations later.
There are several different areas [ID_1] in my shapefile. I'm working with ArcGIS Desktop and I have no permission to install other moduls for arcpy

Comment: I would create a list of list with [oid, id_1, Point_z] then sort `l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1],x[2]))` then read into a Dictionary and select by Dictionary values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question with this code by myself. I'm pretty sure, that there is a more efficient way, but maybe somebody has a similiar issue and can use it.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inLAS[:-4] + '_POLE_POINTS.SHP','ID_1') as max_cursor:
    for row in max_cursor:
        mast_value = sorted({row[0] for row in max_cursor})
        for mast in mast_value:
            reset_layers("POLES")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("POLES", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"ID_1\" = " + str(mast))
            if int(arcpy.GetCount_management("POLES")[0]) > 0:
                cur = arcpy.SearchCursor("POLES", '', '', '',  'POINT_Z')
                row = next(iter(cur))
                minimum = maximum = row.getValue('POINT_Z')
                for row in cur:  
                    elev = row.getValue('POINT_Z')
                    fid = row.getValue('FID')
                    if elev < minimum:   
                        minimum = elev
                    if elev > maximum:   
                        maximum = elev
                        fid_max = fid
                 del cur
             max_FID.append(fid_max)
max_FID.sort()
print(max_FID)
reset_layers("POLES")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("POLES", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"FID\" in (" + str(max_FID)[1:-1] + ")")
if int(arcpy.GetCount_management("POLES")[0]) > 0:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("POLES", out_PMX)
```